# How to retrieve data from mongoose sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
get: function (code) {
    console.log('Retrieving model for code : ', code);
    let database = UTILS.getDatabase('databaseName');
    return database.models.modelName.find({})
        .then(function (users) {
            console.log(' ----------- ', users);
            return users;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return '{success: "false", msg: "Error found : ' + error + '"}';
        });
}
```

This code is running without any errors, but the function that calls "get" couldn't find any record, while callback function prints around 8-9 records in console. I know this is callback functionality, but I need this to be happen sequentially.

I also tried to use yield `return yield database.models.modelName.find({})` with `*` function, but getting `{}`, an empty object.

Please suggest a way to avoid callback and get data from mongodb.

Thanks Julien, but I can't use callback, because the function which is calling "get" has logic to process object return from mongoose.

Hi Ravi, here is complete flow of this process stack. Route -> Controller -> Facade -> Service -> Dao (the code I posted is belongs to Dao layer get function)

This looks typical typed language solution, but I need this to be in this way.

a Service layer function could collect data from multiple model and could be processed collectively, so callback process doesn't fulfill my requirement here.

I am completely stuck, Thanks for help :)

**Router :**

```
app.route('/nodics/users')
.get(CONTROLLER.UserController.get)
.post(CONTROLLER.UserController.set);
```

**Controller:**

```
get: function (request, response, error) {      
    let users = FACADE.UserFacade.get();
    response.json(users);
}
```

**Facade :**

```
get: function (code) {
    console.log('inside Facade call....', code);
    return SERVICE.UserService.get(code);
}
```

**Service :**

```
get: function (code) {
    console.log('inside Service call....', code);
    return DAO.UserDao.get(code);
}
```

Dao method is already there at top. This is a sample layered implementation. but I just want to to be implemented in this way only. so that I can call, DAO layer method anytime and from anywhere in the Service layer.

Use Case:

```
1. I want to add one item into cart, so I pass, PID, SKUID and quantity to the router, which simply pass controls to controller.
2. Controller pass it to facade and Service.
3. In service layer
     1. Call another service to check if quantity is valid
     2. Call DAO to load product item
     3. Call another DAO to load Inventory (or use from first call)
     4. Call another DAO to load price item, based on local and currency, or other parameters.
     5. Finally load ORDER and add this item into it and save it
     6. Return order item to facade layer
4. In Facade, apply filter to return only fields required to expose as service.
```

So If I want to implement this use case, getting data by callback from mongoose will not help.

So please suggest me the way to get data directly from mongoose without using callback.

Comment: can you show how and where you are calling `get` function?

Comment: i wanted to see the code, how you are calling the get, and storing its result

Comment: are you getting the data in facade and service, where is it breaking actually?

Comment: I am getting Promise object at the end of Controller and using Promise object, I can retrieve actual data. but problem is same, Promise.Then() is not sequential, so If I use this in DAO, get method will be returned before executing .then() block. so I can print it in .then block but can't return it to service layer.

Comment: are you getting some value in code in service and facade ?

Comment: Yes, promise object. And using promise I can get the actual value but again it will be callback, because it uses .then()

Comment: why dont you change your controller to this:
`FACADE.UserFacade.get().then(function(users){
       response.json(users);
});`

Comment: why wont it work??

Comment: Updated my question with one use case, please go through

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback to your function and call it from your promises:

```
get: function (code, cb) {
    console.log('Retrieving model for code : ', code);
    let database = UTILS.getDatabase('databaseName');
    return database.models.modelName.find({})
        .then(function (users) {
            console.log(' ----------- ', users);
            cb(users);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            cb({success: "false", msg: "Error found : ' + error + '"});
        });
}
```